# how to do random fade text in jquery &html

Tags: jquery, html

How to do random text in fade effect 
jquery & html

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fade').list_ticker({
        speed:5000,
        effect:'fade'
    });     
})
```

Html

```
   <ul id="fade">
      <li>
        <span class="quote">quote_1</span><br />
        <span class="author">-author_1-</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="quote">quote_2</span><br />
        <span class="author">-author_2-</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="quote">quote_3</span><br />
        <span class="author">-author_3-</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="quote">quote_4</span><br />
        <span class="author">-author_4-</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="quote">quote_5</span><br />
        <span class="author">-author_5-</span>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Please help me with this problem. I realy don't know how to do it in jquery.

I tried to search for some information, but I cant find anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "random text"? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Seems you want a carousel with an option to randomize what is first shown. Just search for `jQuery carousel` or `jQuery slideshow` and see which one fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var randomiza;
$(function(){
$("#fade li").hide();
 randomiza = function(){
    $("#fade li").hide();
    var quotes = $("#fade li");
    var indice = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
    (quotes).eq(indice-1).fadeIn(1500);
}
setInterval(randomiza, 3000);    

});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/5nzbw8gz/5/

Answer (score -2):

random option 
once chooses   quote_5 and start loop ->quote_5 ->quote_1 ->quote_2
next time chooses  quote_3 and start loop ->quote_4 ->quote_5 ->quote_1

Comment: Is this an answer to fix your problem or is this a continuation of your question? If it is an answer could you please elaborate? If not then there is an edit button you could add this to your initial post.